# wordpress bouncing from http to https and back to http then finally to https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, https, http-redirect

My Wordpress site is `https://www.example.com` in the Wordpress admin under `Settings/general`

I am using `Simple SSL` plugin. Here is my `.htaccess`.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com
#RewriteRule (.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com[nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-admin
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/wp-admin/ [R,L]
</IfModule>



# BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[2.5.22]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL
```

For some reason when go to `example.com` it does 3 redirects from http->https->http->https

```
example.com
https://example.com
http://www.example.com
https://www.example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If X-Forwarded-Proto is the way to determine whether the Request comes via HTTPS or not, I believe you can replace everything with this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.org%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Put it BEFORE the WP block in the .htaccess. If the SSL is being handled in your Apache directly, replace the RewriteCond-line with `RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80`

Comment: if i do this it never navigates to `https://www.example.com`. It stays at `https:\\example.com`. It actually does this even if i delete everything from the htaccess

Comment: Which one did you use, the one with `X-Forwarded-Proto` or with `SERVER_PORT`? Did you also try the other one?

Comment: i tried `x-forwarded-proto`. i also tried the other. both cause the bounce

Comment: That's odd. Is there anything else in your .htaccess aside from the normal WP block?

Comment: thats really all that's there. I do have a `Deny`

Comment: Are you using a service like CloudFlare? Do you see the requests & redirect responses in your access logs?

Comment: Yes i have CloudFlare. I paused it for 2 minutes and tested and the extra redirect went away. So its really the culprit. Any ideas on how to resolve it with CloudFlare?

Comment: I guess you have a page rule set up that does "Always use HTTPS" for all of your domain ("http://*.example.org" or similar). Make that more specific ("http://www.example.org") and it will let you handle the http://example.org redirects yourself.